# I cant enter the password while I can enter other fields in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I can't seem to pass the password and everything works except from password. I useschema I get the error but it could be problem in my functions because I hashed the password . I cant seem to find what's the problem

my server

```js
const express = require('express')
const colors = require('colors')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const {errorHandler} = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

//connect to database
connectDB()

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: 'Welcome to the support desk api'})
})

app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/userRoutes'))

app.use(errorHandler)


app.listen( PORT, () => console.log(`Port started on ${PORT}`))
```

my mongoose schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your name']
    },
    email : {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
        unique: true
    },
     password : {
        type: String,
        required : [true, 'Please add a password'],
     },
    isAdmin : {
        type: Boolean,
        required : true,
        default: false,
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

my model where i use functions for registering login

```js
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const User = require('../models/userModel')


// @desc register a new user
// @ route api/users
// @acess Public
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body

    //validation
    if(!name || !email || !password) {
        res.status(400)
       throw new Error('Please iclude all fields')
    }

    //find if user already exist
    const userExists = await User.findOne({email})

    if (userExists){
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('User already Exist')
    }

    //hash password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

    //create user
    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        hashedPassword,
    })

    if(user) {
        res.status(201).json({
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email
        })
    } else {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('Invalid user Data')
    }

})

// @desc register a new user
// @ route api/users/login
// @acess Public
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    res.send('Login Route')
})

module.exports = {
    registerUser,
    loginUser
}
```

my result from post man
[Result from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9sMa.png)

Comment: Your schema field is named `password`, not `hashedPassword`. You want `{ name, email, password: hashedPassword }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after you create you should use password: hashedPassword

Comment: That should have been a comment, and the question should have been closed

Comment: The question that includes that answer shows lack of research and it should be closed so the answer should have been a comment